# What NIC is connected to what network in VMware VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a requirement to create a VMware VM that must be connected to multiple networks (one vNIC for each network). IPs are assigned statically and are supplied via OVF environment properties. The IPs must be assigned to interfaces from inside the VM with a custom script (please let me know if there's an easier standard way to do it). The question is how can I know what interface is connected to what virtual network. I use CentOS7 as the guest OS. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each interface will be assigned a Mac address that will be visable in both the VMware product you are using (assuming ESXi or Workstation) as well as in the guest OS. Just match them up and you have your interface to vNIC mappings.